# Waking up from suspend triggers ultrabook CPU fan to go mental: how to diagnose and fix?

Tags: suspend, 17.04, cpu, fan

Thinkpad X1 Carbon 5th generation ultrabook with i7 Kabylake CPU running Ubuntu 17.04 has its fan go full steam if the laptop is woken up from sleep/suspend. Without any sleep/suspend the laptop's fan is basically "off" or silent, even for hours. So somehow the waking-up must be triggering the fan to go mental. Note that the BIOS is up-to-date. Any ideas how to further diagnose and fix?

Comment: Closely related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=225158 and https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/5ze76f/t470_nonstop_fan_after_resuming_from_sleep/

Comment: ... https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191181 or rather https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196129